# Works in IRB from Terminal but not in Sublime

Tags: ruby

At first I was running into issues with this code in both the Terminal's IRB and in Sublime but after troubleshooting them, it was fixed in IRB but I was still getting the error msg (listed below) in Sublime. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

P.S. I'm a Ruby noob

This is the code that I put in Sublime Text

> ```
> require 'rubygems'
> require 'RedCloth'
>
> r = RedCloth.new("this is a test *test* of _using RedCloth_")
> puts r.to_html
> ```

This is the error message that I get in Sublime when I run it

> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- RedCloth (LoadError)  from
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51:in`
>   require'     from
>   /Users/StevenW/Documents/Code/ruby/beginning_ruby/test.rb:2:in
>   `' [Finished in 9.0s with exit code 1] [shell_cmd: ruby
>   "/Users/StevenW/Documents/Code/ruby/beginning_ruby/test.rb"] [dir:
>   /Users/StevenW/Documents/Code/ruby/beginning_ruby] [path:
>   /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're default ruby is set properly so that Sublime can run it.

I see that you are using `rvm`

`rvm use 2.0.0 --default`

Then run the following command.

`gem install RedCloth`

Run it again in Sublime. It should work.

Comment: Hey Anbiniyar, thank you so much for your help. If I could ask another question. How come it worked in IRB but not Sublime? How do I check the ruby version of my RVM in sublime?

Comment: How did you run your IRB? Did you do something like this? `rvm use 2.0,0` followed by `gem install RedCloth` and then `irb`. If that is the case, Sublime was not using your `rvm ruby` but instead `system ruby`. The `--default` flag changes your `system ruby` to use `ruby 2.0.0`. As to how to check your `ruby version` from Sublime, try adding this to your code: `puts RUBY_VERSION`. That should print out the version.